# Fetch Strategy Ignored

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a simple association using Hibernate 2.5:

And we want this to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But even when we explicitly set `OUTER-JOIN` to true we still get an `INNER JOIN`.

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this Hibernate FAQ : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#Hibernate_ignores_my_outerjointrue_or_fetchjoin_setting_and_fetches_an_association_lazily_using_n1_selects

You have 2 options, use the Criteria API (which will use the outer-join setting) or explicitly use LEFT OUTER JOIN in your HQL query.